# Get value of Javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, object

i have the following js object from a json string.

```
[
  {
    "cmd": "GetImage",
    "code": 0,
    "value": {
      "Image": {
        "bright": 128,
        "channel": 0,
        "contrast": 128,
        "hue": 128,
        "saturation": 128,
        "sharpen": 128
      }
    }
  }
]
```

How i can access the value of bright?

Thanks Kevin

Comment: Assuming you've parsed the data: `data[0].value.Image.bright`

Comment: technically that's not an object, it's an array which has a single index, and at that index the variable there is an object.

Answer (score 2):

First of all that is an `Array` of `Objects`
You can use `yourArray[0].value.Image.bright`

Answer (score 1):

As the property resides in the first index position, use `0` as the index, then chain the property names with dot (`.`) until the targeted property.

Try `data[0].value.Image.bright`

```js
var data = [{"cmd":"GetImage","code":0,"value":{"Image":{"bright":128,"channel":0,"contrast":128,"hue":128,"saturation":128,"sharpen":128}}}]

console.log(data[0].value.Image.bright)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have array with multiple elements similar like above, then you can iterate through each element and then `item.value.Image.bright` will give you the expected result

```js
var items = [
  {
    "cmd": "GetImage",
    "code": 0,
    "value": {
      "Image": {
        "bright": 128,
        "channel": 0,
        "contrast": 128,
        "hue": 128,
        "saturation": 128,
        "sharpen": 128
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "cmd": "GetImage1",
    "code": 1,
    "value": {
      "Image": {
        "bright": 129,
        "channel": 0,
        "contrast": 128,
        "hue": 128,
        "saturation": 128,
        "sharpen": 128
      }
    }
  }
]

//Here for loop will iterate twice
for(var item of items){
  console.log(item.value.Image.bright);
}
```